# Ember data help! Unable to de-serialise JSON to model

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using:

Ember 1.10.0
Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.15

I have a model like this:

```
//models//acceptedtask.js
import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.Model.extend({
    userAggregateId: DS.attr('number'),
    taskAggregateId: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I get this back from the server:

```
{"acceptedTask":{"id":5,"userAggregateId":1,"taskAggregateId":3,"name":"Clean table"}}
```

Whenever I get this json back ember throws the following error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for task-management@model:acceptedtask: in an object passed to `push`
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:22992:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14489:15)
    at Ember.Object.extend.push (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74317:15)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74783:24
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10749:27)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$_adapterRun (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74759:32)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74780:16
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:60990:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:61002:17)
```

Is anyone able to help me with this? I feel like I'm missing something basic after trolling half the internet for similar problems :(

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your model and response.  However, to get it to populate correctly I had to change the response from

```
{"acceptedTask":{"id":5,"userAggregateId":1,"taskAggregateId":3,"name":"Clean table"}}
```

to

```
{"acceptedtask":{"id":5,"userAggregateId":1,"taskAggregateId":3,"name":"Clean table"}}
```

Other than that, it looked good.  However, I received the following warning instead of the error you indicated:

```
"WARNING: Encountered "acceptedTask" in payload, but no model was found for model name "acceptedTask"
```

Comment: Thanks :) I worked out that the model names returned from my API are case sensitive to the ember model names..makes sense -_-